# Unknown character is being added to the last of the string

Tags: c++, string, raw-input

Below is a part of my application being designed in C++. The below code fragment displays *** as password input by user.The code is used in two places in the program one works fine and the other place it shows a unknown character at the end of `enterdPassword`.

It works fine here.the entered password is saved in a file for further use.

```
if(FirstRun()){
    display_welcome_text_first_run();

    cout<<"\nEnter A Password(Max 13 character): ";
    for(i=0; i<13; i++){
        x = getch();
        if(x == '\r'){ break; }
        putchar('*');
        p[i]=x;
    }

    p[i+1]='\0';
    string pwd(p);
    ofstream o(PASSWORD_FILE,ios::binary);
    o <<pwd<<endl;
    o.close();
```

Here it shows the error it shows a unknown character at the end of `enterdPassword`.

```
bool verifyPassword(){
    string savdPassword;
    char px[20], x;
    int i;
    cout<<"Enter Your Password To Continue: ";

    for(i=0; i<13; i++){
        x = getch();
        if(x == '\r'){ break; }
        putchar('*');
        px[i] = x;
    }
    px[i+1] = '\0';

    string enterdPassword(px);

    ifstream pp(PASSWORD_FILE, ios::binary);
    pp>>savdPassword;
    pp.close();
    cout<<endl<<enterdPassword;<<" "<<savdPassword; //for debugging
    if(enterdPassword == savdPassword){
        return true;
    }
    else{return false;}
}
```

Image of program run.
[image: Image of program run.]

I don't understand why the same code(only with different variables) give work differently How can I correct the code to work correctly as desired?.

Comment: I think that, in both cases, `px[i+1] = '\0';` should be `px[i] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change

```
p[i+1]='\0';
```

to

```
p[i]='\0';
```

because `i` has been already incremented after the last loop iteration.

However, it's better not to use raw character arrays at all:

```
string pwd;
for(i=0; i<13; i++){
    x = getch();
    if(x == '\r'){ break; }
    pwd += x;
}
```

Comment: this did solve my problem, but I still don't understand why the first implementation did not go wrong

Comment: @Pushkar in the first function you could have `p` initialized with zeros (by chance or if it's a global/static variable)

Comment: nope it's just being initialized the same way in as in case 1.

Comment: @Pushkar you didn't provide the full code, so one can only guess. I see that almost for sure it's *not* the same way, because in the second case `px` is a local (and uninitialized) array, and in the first case there's no local variable `p`.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the case when x == '\r' . Here for that value of i px[i] is not stored. You store the '\0' character in the i+1 th position.

*You should change this as px[i] (For the i at which \r was entered)gives the inncorrect character.*

```
px[i]=='\0'
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity's sake lets say you enter a single-letter password (doesn't matter what it is).

You enter the loop and the variable `i` is equal to `0`. Then the loop iterates, and `i` is increased to `1`, and you read the newline (or rather the `'\r'`) and you break out of the loop, with `i` equal to `1`. Then you terminate the string at `i + 1`, so you set the terminator at `px[2]`, one beyond the length of the entered string.